# Error while installing vue CLI: npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ulp-rename":"0.0.33",'

Tags: npm, vue-cli

I had an older version of vue CLI and i want to upgrade to CLI 3, so first what I did is unistall the previous version:

```
npm uninstall vue-cli -g
```

Then tried to install:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ulp-rename":"0.0.33",'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\31089\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-02T11_48_31_187Z-debug.log
```

The complete log information can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/CU3QRMU3)
My `node` version: `v12.14.0`
My `npm` version: `6.13.4`
And I tried

```
npm cache clean --force
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, if you run command prompt window as an administrator, then first do

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then can install **successfully**.

Comment: npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.